# Xpages - Creating Repeat or View from different database with ACL set to No Access

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, xpages-ssjs

I am trying to create a repeat element from a view in a different database that does not allow Anonymous ACL access.

- PubDb.nsf has ACL set for user Anonymous to Author
- PrivDb.nsf has ACL set for user Anonymous and Default "no access".

The database, PrivDb has information that I want to secure, but would like to pull a couple of views out for public display.

When I create a repeat in PubDb.nsf using PrivDb.nsf view, It will not display any data.  I am able to use sessionAsSigner to get SSJS to see the view and open documents at the server side level, but when I try to display the view or repeat elements there is no data ?  If I change ACL in PrivDb for Anonymous to Reader everything works, but now the entire db is open to Anonymous access.

I understand that sessionAsSigner and sessionAsSignerWithFullAccess allows me to use db signers effective rights, and I can use SSJS to access the notesdocuments and publish data using computed fields for individual docs, but I can't find any information that tells me I can or can't display an xpages element (repeat or view) using the sessionAsSigner.  Maybe I can create a lotusscript agent that populates the block?

Below is the code I use to create the repeat element in PubDb.nsf.  Note, I assigned the DB twice, once in Application and again in View because when I didn't use sessionAsSigner in the view's computed value I would get prompted for authentication, and it's required in the app field.

```
<xp:this.data>
    <xp:dominoView var="view2">
        <xp:this.databaseName><![CDATA[${javascript:
            var DB:NotesDatabase=sessionAsSigner.getDatabase(database.getServer(),"PrivDb.nsf");
            DB;
            }]]>
        </xp:this.databaseName>
    <xp:this.viewName><![CDATA[${javascript:
        var dbOther:NotesDatabase = sessionAsSignerWithFullAccess.getDatabase(database.getServer(), "PrivDb.nsf");
        var lookupView:NotesView = dbOther.getView( "PrivView" );
        lookupView.recycle();
        lookupView}]]>
    </xp:this.viewName>
    </xp:dominoView>
</xp:this.data>
<div class="container">
    <div class="page-header">
        <h1>This is a test.</h1>
    </div>
    <xp:br></xp:br>
    <xp:br></xp:br>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-1"></div>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <xp:repeat id="repeat1" rows="30" var="playerData"
                value="#{view2}" repeatControls="true">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1"
                        value="#{playerData.$5}">
                    </xp:text>
                    hcp: &#160;
                    <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField5"
                        value="#{playerData.$6}">
                    </xp:text>
                    <xp:br></xp:br>
                    <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField2"
                        value="#{playerData.$7}">
                    </xp:text>
                    &#160; &#160;
                    <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField3"
                        value="#{playerData.$8}">
                    </xp:text>
                    &#160; &#160;
                    <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField4"
                        value="#{playerData.$9}">
                    </xp:text>
                    <xp:br></xp:br>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1"></div>
            </xp:repeat>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Aside answer from Per you should also consider using author/reader functionality in PrivDb.nsf. Elevating rights using sessionAsSigner is not exactly a best practice from security perspective.

Comment: Thanks, Egor.  I agree best practice is using standard authentication and security practices.  In this case we weighed our options and this seems to be the best option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try changing your repeat to return for instance the view entries directly using sessionAsSigner instead of going through a view data source. So in your case:

```
<xp:repeat id="repeat1" rows="30" var="playerData">
    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:
        sessionAsSigner.getDatabase(database.getServer(), "PrivDb.nsf").getView("PrivView").getAllEntries();
    }]]></xp:this.value>
...
</xp:repeat>
```

Comment: Hi Per, thanks for the response.  It kind of works.  I was able to get the rows to iterate and used the
    <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField7" value="#{javascript:playerData.getUniversalID()}">
      </xp:text>
which showed doc unids, but otherwise I get an error: 
Error getting property '$5' from bean of type lotus.domino.local.ViewEntry .  It happens regardless of ACL settings.  I tried : playerData.getDocument().getItemValueString("createdBy") and some others, but can't seem to display data.  Will keep trying.

Comment: Thanks Per, I used the lines below to access columns data:

<xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1" value="#{javascript:playerData.getColumnValues()[0]}">
</xp:text>
<xp:text escape="true" id="computedField2" value="#{javascript:playerData.getColumnValues()[1]}">
</xp:text>
....
Now the pager control gives me a runtime error of divide by zero when I page forward, but I'm almost there.

Comment: done, removed the "Create Controls at Page Creation" from the Repeat Option and it's working like a charm.  Thanks for your assistance!

Comment: Great to hear. I updated my answer to not include repeatControls="true". Remembet to accept the answer. Thanks.